# Viewport render is oddly slow with CPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I don't know If this is normal but when I turn CPU for viewport rendering it lags the device (sluggish cursor etc) but when I turn on the GPU its fine. I know that a GPU is a lot faster than a CPU but this seems a bit questionable considering its not a old CPU. Is there any way to fix this?

My laptop specs

Name : hp victus 16-r0035nt

Gpu: Rtx 4060 laptop gpu

Cpu: intel i5 13500H

Ram: 16gb 5200mhz

Comment: This is exactly what a gpu is built for.
A decent gpu is some magnitudes faster than a cpu.
A scene can get pretty fast so complex that any CPU will feel stuck. So yes, this is normal.

How to fix this?
Use your GPU. It's what the GPU is there.

Comment: Why do you find it odd that a busy CPU causes slowness of the computer?

Comment: idk it felt abnormally slow

Comment: It's not that weird, but I wouldn't expect the scheduler of a modern cpu to slam the system so hard that UI suffers

Comment: @AllenSimpson I've had scenes where the system suffered when using the CPU, so it's really no surprise to me.

Comment: @AllenSimpson I mean yeah thats why I posted this question